# segmentation fault when I set the a value to the end of a string

Tags: c

I wrote a simple function that reverse a string. I try not to allocate a temp char for swap by using the last character '\0' at the end of char*. However, it reports the segmentation fault at *end = *str;

Could anyone explain the reason?

Thank you very much!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void reverse(char* str)
{
    char* end = str;
    char* i = str;
    char* j = str;
    while(*end)
        ++end;
    j = end;
    *end = *str;
    while(j > i)
    {
        *i = *j;
        ++i;
        *j = *i;
        ++j;
    }
    while(i < end)
    {
        *i = *(i+1);
        ++i;
    }
    *i = '\0';
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* str_test1;
    char* str_test2;
    str_test1 = (char*) malloc(10);
    str_test2 = (char*) malloc(2);
    str_test1 = "abcdefjhi";
    str_test2 = "a";
    printf("input str1=%s, str2=%s", str_test1, str_test2);
    reverse(str_test1);
    reverse(str_test2);
    printf("output str=%s, str2=%s", str_test1, str_test2);
    free(str_test1);
    free(str_test2);
}
```

[After I change the code to the following, it works.]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
void reverse(char* str)
{
    char* end = str;
    char* i = str;
    char* j = str;
    while(*end)
        ++end;
    j = end;
    *end = *str;
    **--j;**
    while(j > i)
    {
        *i = *j;
        ++i;
        *j = *i;
        **--j;**
    }
    while(i < end)
    {
        *i = *(i+1);
        ++i;
    }
    *i = '\0';
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* str_test1;
    char* str_test2;
    str_test1 = (char*) malloc(10);
    str_test2 = (char*) malloc(2);
    strcpy(str_test1, "abcdefjhi");
    strcpy(str_test2,"a");
    printf("input str1=%s, str2=%s\n", str_test1, str_test2);
    reverse(str_test1);
    reverse(str_test2);
    printf("output str=%s, str2=%s\n", str_test1, str_test2);
    free(str_test1);
    free(str_test2);
}
```

Comment: You're doing all that, just so you don't have a temp variable?

Comment: Where do you allocate extra space in case one string is longer than the other?

Comment: hi all, I just added my main function where I call the reverse(char * ) function for a string.

Comment: `str_test1 = "abcdefjhi";
    str_test2 = "a";` you get memory leak here

Comment: @triclosan Could you please explain a little?

Comment: Since it's tagged c++, why don't you use `string` and use `std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());`.

Answer (score 5):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
str_test1 = (char*) malloc(10);
str_test2 = (char*) malloc(2);
str_test1 = "abcdefjhi";
str_test2 = "a";
```

You probably wanted this:

```
str_test1 = (char*) malloc(10);
str_test2 = (char*) malloc(2);
strcpy(str_test1, "abcdefjhi");
strcpy(str_test2, "a");
```

Or this:

```
char str_test1[10] = "abcdefjhi";
char str_test[2]   = "a";
```

What you currently have allocates memory, and then overwrites the pointer to the memory you allocated with a pointer to a read-only string literal, and that's a good way to earn a segfault.

Either of the above replacements will give you a writeable string that you can safely reverse in place.

Comment: Good job. I don't need to post my answer then:)

Comment: @Joe Z, Thank you so much for pointing out the strcpy issue for me. However, I don't think the rest of the code has problem after I change the ++j to --j (my mistake :(). Actually, I used the place that holds '\0' as the swap place, that's why I need the second loop the shift the right part of the reversed string and set the '\0' to *end.

Comment: @MikeXu : I missed that detail in the first sentences of your description.  I will remove that portion of the answer.  I realized what you were trying to do as I wrote my answer.